# How to pause/stop video in Android from my application

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In Android how can i pause video player from my application. 
I am able to achieve this for music player but not for video. 
(Note: my application is different from video player.  Video is not running in my application. )

Comment: This site is not for sharing codes... post part of your code so far so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Android how can i pause video player from my application

Contact the authors of the video player you want to control, and ask them if they have an API to allow third-party apps to control their video player.

In general, apps cannot control other apps this way.

> I am able to achieve this for music player

It is possible that there is some music player that has a documented and supported API that you are using. Or, perhaps you are attacking some music player with security issues. Many Android developers are capable of creating a music player that cannot be controlled by third-party apps, so please do not assume that whatever you did will work across all music players.